# If Statement in Jquery dependent on a checkbox being checked?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I would like to Add a if statement to surround some code. I need my if statement to be (but in **jquery**):

```
If (chkSurety.checked = true){
SuretyFullName: { required: true }, // This is validation plugin and must stay like this.
SuretyIDNumber: { required: true}, 
SuretyPhysicalAddress: { required: true }, 
SuretyHomeTel: { required: true}, 
SuretyPlace: { required: true}, 
SuretyDay: { required: true }, 
SuretyMonth: { required: true } 
}
Else
{
SuretyFullName: { required: false },
SuretyIDNumber: { required: true}, 
SuretyPhysicalAddress: { required: true }, 
SuretyHomeTel: { required: true}, 
SuretyPlace: { required: true}, 
SuretyDay: { required: true }, 
SuretyMonth: { required: true } 
}
```

This if statement is C# i need it to be jquery. This is inside a event already so don't want the checkbox.checked to be the event, just need the above code in jquery please.

Thanks in advance, if you need more info just ask :)

Comment: You don't want jQuery, you want JavaScript. have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: Sorry i need to use jquery is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly.

```
SuretyFullName: { required: function (element) { if ($('#chkSuretyShip').is(':checked')) { return true } else { return false} } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you checkbox has an ID of `chkSurety`, and that all you want to do is update the `SuretyFullName` object's state, per the code given in your question:

```
SuretyFullName.required = $('#chkSurety').is(':checked');
```

or (more efficiently) without jQuery:

```
SuretyFullName.required = document.getElementById('chkSurety').checked;
```

It *appears* that you're trying to create some rules for the jQuery validation plugin, hence:

```
// set the default rules
var rules = {
    SuretyFullName: { required: false },
    SuretyIDNumber: { required: true}, 
    SuretyPhysicalAddress: { required: true }, 
    SuretyHomeTel: { required: true}, 
    SuretyPlace: { required: true}, 
    SuretyDay: { required: true }, 
    SuretyMonth: { required: true } 
 };

 // override the full name rule, based on the checkbox
 rules.SuretyFullName.required = $('#chkSurety').is(':checked');

 $('#fmrMain').validate({
      rules: rules,
      ...
 });
```

Comment: sorry i need a if statement this wont work for what i need to do, i just tried it as a test and its not right.

Comment: @Pomster if the required result is exactly as in your question then the code above would work.  If you need _additional_ things to happen depending on the check button state, you should have said so.

Comment: i cant have .required my format needs to be: SuretyFullName: { required: true } and have the if statement souround that

Comment: @Pomster then you need to explain what _you_ think `SuretyFullName: { required: true }` means, because to a JS programmer it means setting the nested property `.required` of another object that itself has a property called `SuretyFullName` to `true`.

Comment: Please look at my edit and u will see that the if statement needs to be one if statement regarding my checkbox only please adjust your answer.

Comment: @Pomster  nope, I'm done with this question.  We've all shown you how to check the button state, per the subject of your question.  The real problem is that you haven't explained what the weird syntax _within_ your `if / else` blocks is supposed to do.

Comment: You have not answered my question at all i need one if statement to surround meany object. the items can only be SuretyFullName: { required: true/false }, your answer is using my object when i needs to be a one if statement using the checkbox like at @Rory McCrossan's answer, unfortunately it does not work. So even tho your code may work is is not what i asked!

Comment: @Pomster look, I can't put this any more simply.  Checking the value of the checkbox is trivial.  Doing the `if/else` is trivial.  What no-one can figure out is what the hell you're trying to do _within_ those blocks.  That's the crux of your problem, but **it isn't what you asked** !!

Comment: All the other answer are what i'm trying to do! you just got the up votes for the wrong answer, but thanks for trying enjoy the day.

Comment: @pomster nope, I got up votes for answering the question you _actually asked_.  I've now seen your question from yesterday, and now understand what you're trying to do, but frankly I can't now be bothered because of your attitude.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($("#chkSurety").is(":checked")) {
    // rest of code...
}
```

Comment: Need the else statement to, and that if is not working, i had a green line underlineing the if

Answer (score 1):

Simply put this:

```
var yourObject = {SuretyFullName: { required: chkSurety.checked }};
```

If you really need `if`-syntax for some reason:

```
var yourObject = {};
if (chkSurety.checked) {
    yourObject.SuretyFullName = true;
} else {
    yourObject.SuretyFullName = false;
}
```

Note: `if (chkSurety.checked == true)` is redundant, `if (chkSurety.checked)` is better.

Answer (score 1):

*If you can help it don't include the entire JQuery library if it's just as easy to use pure JavaScript*

However as it's a requirement to use JQuery :-)

```
if ($('#chkSurety').is(":checked")) {
    // checked
} else {
    // not checked
}
```

​
​
http://jsfiddle.net/XXHrE/3/ - to test it out...

Comment: My question already looks like that so that's a effortless answer :|, i have requirement's to use jquery.

Comment: @Pomster is this more like it?

Comment: @Greg `.attr('checked')` is **not** the right way to check the state of a checkbox.

Comment: @Greg yup, it looks like everyone else's now :)